# ansible local file path for unarchive

Tags: ansible

I have what I think is a fairly common task of taking a local archive file, transferring it to a server, and extracting it there. I'm using the `unarchive` module for this but struggling with an elegant way to deal with the local filename always being different because the filename includes the software version. For example, here's a excerpt from a playbook:

```
- name: Upload code
  unarchive: src={{payload_file}} dest={{install_dir}}
```

I can run this and use `-e` to set the variable:

```
ansible-playbook -e payload_file=/tmp/payload-4.2.1.zip -i production deploy.yml
```

My question is **is this the best way to handle this situation**? All the docs have hardcoded example file names and paths and I haven't seen any evidence in the docs that makes a variable that will be different each deployment straightforward to set.

Comment: We have version numbers defined as variables in host_var or, more often in group_var files.  Then when we want to test a new package we just update the version in the test/staging group_vars file, and when we're ready to upgrade production we update the production group_vars file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While passing extra args on the command line will work, I generally don't like having to type to run the job -- this is to say that I don't think your solution is inelegant or bad in any way.

However, if you're willing to change your process a little, you can avoid having to add options when calling your playbook.

Option 1: Put the `payload-version.zip` file in a directory and target that directory with a glob.  Any file in that directory will get unarchived (if there's only one file, this achieves the same behavior):

```
- name: Upload code
  unarchive: src={{item}} dest={{install_dir}}
  with_fileglob:
    - /tmp/payloads/*
```

Option 2: Symlink the versioned file to a simple, general name of `payload-latest.zip` and target it with your play (using the modified date or setting a fact for metadata).  I assume you have a build process or script to generate the zip, so add a step to symlink the build version to `payload-latest.zip` and target that in your play.